# Get all directories recursive within directory with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, directory, path

I want to get all directories synchronize within a given directory.

```
<MyFolder>
    |- Folder1
       |- Folder11
       |- Folder12
    |- Folder2
    |- File1.txt
    |- File2.txt
    |- Folder3
        |- Folder31
        |- Folder32
```

I would expect to get an array of:

```
["Folder1/Folder11", "Folder1/Folder12", "Folder2", "Folder3/Folder31", "Folder3/Folder32"]
```

This is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function flatten(lists) {
  return lists.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
}

function getDirectories(srcpath) {
  return fs.readdirSync(srcpath)
  .map(file => path.join(srcpath, file))
  .filter(path => fs.statSync(path).isDirectory());
}

function getDirectoriesRecursive(srcpath) {
  return [srcpath, ...flatten(getDirectories(srcpath).map(getDirectoriesRecursive))];
}
```

Would anyone help me solve the problem above?

Comment: You need to format the elements in the returned array , iterate it and do the formatting on the elements and create new array from the formatted elements to achieve your results

Comment: The function getDirectoriesRecursive() seems to work reasonably well .. maybe you could detail exactly what's going wrong for you? When I run your code I get the output: [ '.\\', 'Folder1', 'Folder1\\Folder11', 'Folder1\\Folder12', 'Folder2', 'Folder3', 'Folder3\\Folder31', 'Folder3\\Folder32' ]

Answer (score 2):

**async**

Here's a highly optimised version using Node's fast [fs.Dirent](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dirent) objects. This approach allows you to skip the expensive `fs.existsSync` and `fs.statSync` calls on every path -

```
const { readdir } =
  require ("fs/promises")

const { join } =
  require ("path")

const dirs = async (path = ".") =>
  Promise.all
    ( (await readdir (path, { withFileTypes: true }))
        .map
          ( dirent =>
              dirent .isDirectory ()
                ? dirs (join (path, dirent.name))
                : []
          )
    )
    .then
      ( results =>
          [] .concat (path, ...results)
      )
```

You use it like this -

```
dirs ("MyFolder") .then (console.log, console.error)
```

---

**sync**

We can rewrite the above function using synchronous functions instead -

```
const { readdirSync } =
  require ("fs")

const { join } =
  require ("path")

const dirsSync = (path = ".") =>
  [].concat
    ( path
    , ...readdirSync (path, { withFileTypes: true })
        .map
          ( dirent =>
              dirent .isDirectory ()
                ? dirsSync (join (path, dirent.name))
                : []
          )
    )
```

You use it like this -

```
console .log (dirsSync ("MyFolder"))
```

This can be further simplified by using `Array.prototype.flatMap` -

```
const { readdirSync } =
  require ("fs")

const { join } =
  require ("path")

const dirsSync = (path = ".") =>
  [ path
  , ...readdirSync (path, { withFileTypes: true })
      .flatMap
        ( dirent =>
            dirent .isDirectory ()
              ? dirsSync (join (path, dirent.name))
              : []
        )
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, you just need to avoid `files` (not directories), so the `getDirectoriesRecursive(srcpath)` function recursion won't throw an error.

This is how should be the final `getDirectoriesRecursive` code:

```
function getDirectoriesRecursive(srcpath) {
  return [srcpath, ...flatten(getDirectories(srcpath).map((p) => {
    try {
      if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
        if (fs.lstatSync(path).isDirectory()) {
          return getDirectoriesRecursive(path);
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }).filter(p => p !== undefined))];
}
```

This is [a live **working Repl Demo**](https://repl.it/@chsdk/Get-directories-names-recursively-with-NodeJS) to show all directories inside `"/opt"`.